# nslog can print the variable, but variable not holding value?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have this:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defauts = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *namestr = [defauts objectForKey:@"savednamestring"];

    NSLog(@"%@",namestr);
    [unusedtext setText:namestr];
    NSLog(@"%@",unusedtext); 
    NSLog(@"%@",unusedtext.text);
```

Now, first `nslog` prints out the content of `namestr`, for instance "Jack".

But the second `nslog` and 3rd `nslog` both give `null`.

when i try to pass `namestr` into entity it gives me an `unrecognized
selector sent to instance` error, and i know it is because of
`namestr` not passing anything into the entity, but how `nslog` print
out `namestr` at the first place. And do i need to convert it into
some sort of format to make it work?

Comment: What is `unusedText`? A NSString?

Answer (score 3):

`unusedText` is probably not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the unusedtext is an UILabel.

There are a few questions:

- Are you using Interface Builder or Storyboard? If yes, did you linked the var with the component?
- If you are not using IB or Storyboard, is this "unusedtext" initialized?
- Are you using ARC? If no, isn't the unusedtext autorelease? Or released before your code?
- If you are using ARC, is the unusedtext marked as STRONG?

Hope to help!

Answer (score 0):

thats because you haven't initialized unusedtext variable.

if it is NSString then do this

```
NSUserDefaults *defauts = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *namestr = [defauts objectForKey:@"savednamestring"];

NSLog(@"%@",namestr);
unusedtext = [NSString stringWithString:namestr];
NSLog(@"%@",unusedtext); 
NSLog(@"%@",unusedtext.text);
```

and if it is a UITextView or UITextfield than do this, instead!

```
NSUserDefaults *defauts = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *namestr = [defauts objectForKey:@"savednamestring"];

NSLog(@"%@",namestr);
UITextField *unusedtext = [[UITextField alloc] init];
[unusedtext setText:namestr];
NSLog(@"%@",unusedtext); 
NSLog(@"%@",unusedtext.text);
```

hope that helps!

Comment: thanks guys, i got that , but the main thing is when i try to pass it into entity it gives me unrecognized selector sent to instance error i tried both ways below:

Comment: @user1844961 what is the type of unusedtext? and are you synthesizing unusedtext and its text property?